# Limit of the function: x if x is rational and -x if x is irrational

Tags: limits, functions

The question is given as follows:

Let

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} x & x\text{ rational} \\ -x & x\text{ irrational}\end{cases}.$$

Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) = 0.$

My first thought is to use the sequential criterion of functions, but I am unsure of how to go about that process. If someone could lead me in the right direction with this problem, it would be a huge help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

$\def\epsilon{\varepsilon}$Note that $|g(x)|=|x|$, no matter whether $x$ is rational or irrational.

Now let $\epsilon>0$.
Choose $\delta=\epsilon$.
Suppose $0<|x-0|<\delta$.
Then $|g(x)-0|=|g(x)|=|x|<\epsilon$.
By definition, $\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

We use the ordinary $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit.

We want to show that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is a $\delta\gt 0$ such that $|g(x)-0|\lt \epsilon$ whenever $|x|\lt \epsilon$. But $|g(x)-0|=|x|$ so we can take $\delta=\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit. If fact, in this case since the limit is $0$, it would be enough to prove that $|g(x)|\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, which is easy since $|g(x)|=|x|$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $-x\le g(x) \le x$, and $\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}x = \underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}-x = 0$, by the squeeze theorem, you have $\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}g(x) = 0$.